# C++ string and char* difference in example

Tags: c++, pointers, char, std, c-strings

This is from hackerrank "Inherited Code" example,

While this works and `what()` returns `n`, if I comment the return in `what` and uncomment the currently commented part `what()` returns junk.

They look the same to me, what is the difference?

```
/* Define the exception here */
struct BadLengthException : public exception {      
    public: 
    int num;
    string stra;
    BadLengthException(int n){
        this->num = n;
        this->stra = to_string(this->num);
    };
    
   const char * what () const throw () {

       return this->stra.c_str();


       //string a = to_string(this->num);
       //return  a.c_str();
   }
};
```

Comment: The crucial difference is the **lifetime** of the two entities. `a` no longer exists when `what` is exited but `stra` does because it's part of the object, not a local variable in the `what` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`string a` is a local (ASDV) in `what()`. It goes out of scope when you return. `a.c_str()` is simply a pointer, it's non-owning and thus doesn't extend the lifetime of the char buffer, therefore it's UB. In case of UB, anything can happen, including returning junk.

Comment: My version is incomplet and incorrekt and doesn't have this acronym.

Comment: @QuentinUK ASDV is automatic storage duration variable, the name the standard refers to what whe commonly call 'local' variables.

Comment: That explains it, thank you. Any idea why my question was downvoted?

Comment: @SandroJijavadze Wasn't me. While this is a basic question, it's also a perfectly valid question to ask I think. Maybe some people forget when they asked such questions...