# Pointer after initialization in an exception subclass

Tags: c++, c++11

I was casually doing some challenges on HackerRank and I stumbled on "Inherited Code", which I've tried to solve with this:

```cpp
class BadLengthException : public exception    {
    private:
        const char* message;
    public:
        BadLengthException(int n_)  {
            this->message = to_string(n_).c_str();
        }
        
        const char * what() const throw() {
            return this->message;
        }
};
```

Since it did not work (the output was empty), I've searched on SO the reason why and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73099621/10301322) on the same problem. I think I do understand the solution proposed, but I'm still very confused about my try:

I get that the string `to_string(n_).c_str()` could be seen as a local variable, like the example in the mentioned question, but why it's still treated as such when `what()` is called? Shouldn't it have been kept in `message` via initialization, thus being available whenever calling `what()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const char*` is a pointer to a raw C-string. It is not a container object (like `std::string`) that would own the string and manage the allocation/deallocation of the buffer that contains the string.

`to_string(int)` returns a `std::string` with a string representation of the number. Then `c_str()` returns a pointer to that string.

But in `this->message = to_string(n_).c_str();`, first a temporary `std::string` object is constructed, and then `message` is set to the pointer to that string. But afterwards, the temporary `std::string` is deleted (which deallocates its buffer), and `message` is now a dangling pointer, that points to memory that is no longer allocated.

One solution would be to instead make `this->message` a `std::string`. And make `what()` return `this->message.c_str()`.

Comment: In conclusion I used what you're suggesting, but I was missing the understanding of the dangling part. Let me ask just another thing: is there a way to avoid said deallocation without recurring to string or other container objects?

Comment: @CcmU you can make `message` be a raw `char[]` buffer instead, and have your constructor `sprintf()` into it, and have `what()` return a pointer to it

Comment: With `std::string` there is no way to avoid the deallocation, the `std::string` object owns the string memory, so it is responsible to allocate/deallocate it. And the C-string pointer is a view to this memory, which remains valid only as long as the `std::string` exists.

Comment: In C++17 there is another function `to_chars()`, to directly write the number string into a given string buffer, without creating a `std::string`. (like `sprintf()`)

Answer (score 2):

`to_string(n_)` is [temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime). It expires at the end of the expression. `c_str()` gets a pointer to the temporary string's data buffer in the short period of time that the `string` is alive, and this pointer is stored, leaving the program with a dangling pointer almost instantly. You're stuck holding the `string`, I'm afraid.

A potential solution:

```cpp
class BadLengthException : public exception    {
    private:
        std::string message;
    public:
        BadLengthException(int n_) :message(to_string(n_)) {
        }
        
        const char * what() const throw() {
            return message.c_str();
        }
};
```

Note: It's a risk to allocate storage in an exception, things get really bad if that storage can't be allocated and you wind up with a throw in a throw, but you can mitigate this with a pre-allocated array, and avoiding the use of `std::string` by going old school with `sprintf` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

`message` is a dangling pointer. The temporary `std::string` returned by `std::to_string` is destroyed at the end of the full expression.

You need to store the message somewhere. The best place is most probably in a `std::string`.

Example:

```cpp
class BadLengthException : public std::exception {
private:
    std::string message;

public:
    BadLengthException(int n_) : message(std::to_string(n_)) {
    }

    const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return message.c_str();
    }
};
```

Note that `const throw()` is the pre C++11 version. Since C++11, it should be `const noexcept override`.

---

A simpler option is to inherit from `std::runtime_error`, which is why that's what people usually do when creating custom exceptions. It provides storage as well as a `what()` override, so all you have to do is:

```
class BadLengthException : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    BadLengthException(int n_) : std::runtime_error(std::to_string(n_)) {
    }
};
```